# Set password of a user using another users password in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I want to alter a users password with the password of another user.

something like -

```
$pswd = SELECT rolpassword FROM pg_authid where rolname='rolea';
ALTER USER 'roleb' WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD $'pswd';
```

I confirmed the above query works by quering the pg_authid and comparing the rolpassword col of both the roles.

> postgres=> select rolname, rolpassword from pg_authid;

```
          rolname          |             rolpassword
---------------------------+-------------------------------------
 rolea                     | md5594fcbdd4e37f23f02887d56a2930588
 roleb                     | md5594fcbdd4e37f23f02887d56a2930588
```

However, when I try to login to roleb with the password of rolea it says invalid password. Later I found that the md5 is generated with the concatenation of md5(password+username) so is there any other way to set a users password to that of another user?

Comment: I cannot see any circumstance wherein you would want to do that. Moreover, I do not see how that would not block `roleb` from connecting, unless they somehow know the password of `rolea` -> if they know, they can set it themselves right? Please explain your actual case.

Comment: `roleb` is created with a random password by the system. `rolea` is the administrator of the db.

Comment: My point exactly: `rolea`, being the admin, surely knows their password so they can connect and alter the password of `roleb` themselves, which they coincidentally have the rights to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work. The md5-hashed password format is tied to a specific username, because PostgreSQL uses the username as a "salt" for the password.

If your password were hashed using SCRAM, then what you did would work.